Burninate [readers] tag?
The readers tag has 5 questions, and no tag wiki excerpt:

Is there a place to find extremely simple stories?
What book is this passage from?
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/21525
What readers are available at the 1,000 word level?
Selecting resources to improve reading for upper-intermediate level?

I'm not sure what the tag is supposed to identify:

"readers" as in "electronic readers", reading devices, such as PDF readers, ipub readers, kindles, etc.
"readers" as in "people who read"
"readers" as in "graded readers"

In this question (the fourth one in the list above) it even seems an incorrect usage of the English term. The author is asking for "readings", as in "things to read".
In all cases it seems we won't miss this tag. If nobody objects, I propose to go ahead and remove it.

AFAIK, the word readers in connection to language learning is usually meant as a shortened phrase of "graded readers." E.g.: What readers are available at the 1,000 word level?, the one you mentioned in your question. Pleco sells a bunch of these as well. Not sure if there are enough questions to merit a tag though.

It seems adequately covered by [reading] and [resources].  (I think I'd be comfortable deleting What percent of the Chinese speakers can read the Latin alphabet? as it's got nothing to do with the Chinese language... any objections?)

@Becky李蓓 it's done. if someone feels we should restore the tag, this thread preserves a list of the questions previously tagged as such

Thanks!  Have a dragon:

